# How to use Chart.js in A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, aframe, virtual-reality, webxr

I am having trouble adding a Chart.js canvas graph inside an A-Frame scene.

You can see my problem and the source code in this [Glitch project](https://glitch.com/%7Echartjs-aframe), or you can view the image here: [image]

You can see the original canvas graph on the left, and on the right, the graph as a texture for an image inside the A-Frame's scene.
This graph is all glitchy, and I can't understand why.

Is there a way to fix the texture? Or another way to add a 2D Chart.js graph inside the scene?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, after careful testing it appears this bug only occurs in Google Chrome. I have tested with Mozilla Firefox and the Oculus browser and it works well.